# Guile `syntax-rules`: Misplaced Ellipsis in Form; How to Write this Macro with Two Ellipses?

Tags: macros, scheme, guile, syntax-rules

I'm trying to, more or less, recreate a `let` construct via `syntax-rules` but it seems to be tripping on the use of two ellipses.

I tried writting it out as so:

```lisp
(define-syntax if-let
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (([binding        value]  ...)
         ([binding2 funct value2])
         ([binding3       value3] ...)) then else) (let ([binding  value]  ...
                                                         [binding2 value2]
                                                         [binding3 value3] ...)
                                                     (if (funct binding2) then else))]))
```

I figured the distinct pattern in the middle of `[binding2 funct value2]` would be able to provide a clear division, in terms of pattern, of when the first pattern ended and when the second one would begin but I keep getting back the error in the title.

The intended result is to be able to do something like

```lisp
(if-let ([var1                  1]
         [diff null? '(1 2 3 4 5)]
         [var2                  2])
    var1
  var2)
```

and get back `2` but being able to have as many `var`s before and after `diff` as remotely desired so the order of the variables used, ultimately, doesn't matter.

Am I missing something obvious? And is this pattern feasibly able to be done with hygenic macros? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with a helper macro, to do the recursion necessary for finding the `funct` things in the middle.

`(if-let-helper processed-bindings processed-conditions input-binding-conditions then else)`

As it recurs, it transfers the information in `input-binding-conditions` into the
`processed-bindings` and `processed-conditions`, stopping when the
`input-binding-conditions` is empty.

```
(define-syntax if-let-helper
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ ([bnd val] ...) (cnd ...) () then else)
     (let ([bnd val] ...)
       (if (and cnd ...) then else))]
    [(_ ([bnd val] ...) (cnd ...) ([binding value] . rest) then else)
     (if-let-helper ([bnd val] ... [binding value]) (cnd ...) rest then else)]
    [(_ ([bnd val] ...) (cnd ...) ([binding funct value] . rest) then else)
     (if-let-helper ([bnd val] ... [binding value]) (cnd ... (funct binding))
                    rest then else)]))

(define-syntax if-let
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (binding-funct-value ...) then else)
     (if-let-helper () () (binding-funct-value ...) then else)]))
```

Using it:

```
> (if-let ([var1                  1]
           [diff null? '(1 2 3 4 5)]
           [var2                  2])
    var1
    var2)
2
```

To explain this, I will step through how this example processes each clause. It initially turns into this `if-let-helper` call:

```
(if-let-helper
  ()
  ()
  ([var1                  1]
   [diff null? '(1 2 3 4 5)]
   [var2                  2])
  var1
  var2)
```

The first two lists start empty because it hasn't processed anything yet.

```
(if-let-helper
  ([var1                  1])
  ()
  ([diff null? '(1 2 3 4 5)]
   [var2                  2])
  var1
  var2)
```

At this point it has processed the first clause and added a binding-value pair to the first "processed-bindings" list. However, there was no `funct` in the first clause, so it didn't add a condition to the second "processed-conditions" list.

```
(if-let-helper
  ([var1                  1]
   [diff       '(1 2 3 4 5)])
  ((null? diff))
  ([var2                  2])
  var1
  var2)
```

At this point it has processed the first two clauses, and added a `(null? diff)` condition to the second list because it saw the `funct` there in the second clause.

```
(if-let-helper
  ([var1                  1]
   [diff       '(1 2 3 4 5)]
   [var2                  2])
  ((null? diff))
  ()
  var1
  var2)
```

It this point it has processed all three clauses, so it hits the base case and transforms into the final `let` and `if`:

```
(let ([var1                  1]
      [diff       '(1 2 3 4 5)]
      [var2                  2])
  (if (and (null? diff))
      var1
      var2))
```

Comment: Geez, I thought I responded to this after you posted it; I'm sorry about that. Thanks a ton for the answer; it was super helpful, detailed, and easy to process. Plus, it helped me solve my problem. Thanks a ton!